# why use * to define string array?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

why we need *names[] rather than names[] here, when I define it as const char names[],it will not execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const int MAX = 4;
int main()
{
  const char *names[] = {
                 "dggg",
                 "ggq",
                 "gg2",
                 "g23",
   };


   for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
   {
      printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have an array of pointers to strings or an array holding only one single string? Without the `*` you can only store 1 string.

Comment: `names` is an array of (4) pointers. Each pointer points to a `const char` which is usually interpreted as a *string*.

Comment: @Gerhardh,hi ,but why use an array of points to integer do not need *,

Comment: Array of integers does not need `*`: `int arr[] = { 1, 2, 42, -1};`; array of **pointers** to int does: `int *ap[] = { NULL, NULL, &errno, NULL };` ... array of char does not need `*`: `char a[] = {'q', 'u', 'u', 'x'};` (note that this array **is not** a string)

Comment: @pmg ok, four point here in the char *names[] ,one point in the char names[]

Comment: most of time, * is equal to [], and you can treat string as  special array. And in your code, *names[] is 2D array.

Comment: @Ace_of_King No, it is not a 2D array, it is a 1D array of pointers. Each pointer may point to a single character, is does not have to be a pointer to the first character of a charcater array. A real 2D array is `char names[][];`

Comment: @Ace_of_King if the * is equal to [], does it mean *names[] equal to []names[]?it looks not reasonable

Comment: @zzzbei formally, *names[] is 1D array like they said. Here you use * to create array of pointers, and in fact strings will be store like array with address. you can change the content of ```char name[4][]={"111","222","333","444"};```, while you cannot change single character in string from ```char * name[4]={"111","222","333","444"};```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string in C is a = **one dimensional character array**. For instance

```
const char string[3] = "abc";
```

What the example code has is an array of C strings i.e.

```
{dggg", "ggq",....}
```

Without the pointer case, it would be like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//const int MAX = 4;

#define NUMBER_OF_STRING 4
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 40

int main()
{

  const char names[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE] = {
                 "dggg",
                 "ggq",
                 "gg2",
                 "g23",
   };


   for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++)
   {
      printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `string` is one element too small, you forgot the final `'\0'`, also in your full example.